# Ответ от сервера в виде html таблицы

Tags: html, ajax, json, asp

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой и из-за недостатка знаний не могу решить сам, поэтому обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Суть:
Необходимо по нажатию на кнопку, показывать блочный элемент и подгружать туда контент в виду html таблицы.

```
$("#ref-show").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "Test.aspx/GetTable",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",          
        success: function (data) {                                          
            $("#ref-content").html(data);              
        }           
    });

    return false;
});
```

на сервере:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static Table GetTable()
    {
        Table result = new Table();  
      // формируем таблицу и заполняем данными из SQL

        return result; 
    }
```

Таблицу заполняю данными с базы SQL. Причем, если ставлю contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", то процедура GetTable() отрабатывает(трэйсом вижу SQL запрос), если же не указываю contentType то загружается вся страница без нужной мне таблицы и SQL запрос не отрабатывает. 
Я видимо где-то страшно туплю, укажите мне пжлста на мою ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось таким образом:

```
$("#ref-show").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "Test.aspx/GetTable",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",          
    success: function (data) {                                          
        $("#ref-content").html(data.d);              
    }           
});

return false;
```

});

С сервера возвращаю строку:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string GetTable()
    {

        Table result = new Table();
        // Формирую html таблицу
        result = Provider.CreateHtmlDataTable();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        result.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));

        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

Может кому пригодится.